# How to block client request in Local Area Network in linux?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, local-area-network

we have a Linux based Local Area Networking, Please find the below architecture diagram

[image]

we have server and client machine connected to through network switch, When any request comes from client we able to block the request in server (192.168.12.10 ). But but client 1 gives the request to client2 any Tcp/IP request we can't control and we can't block in the server , Whether is it Possible ? If its possible please solve my problem. Server side blocking I am using iptables.

**Examples :**

Client1 trying to connect clinet2 using 22 port, now I want to block clinet1 request in server its self ( 192.168.12.10 ) , not  in client, I want to manage all the client request in the main server.

**Edit:**
I want to route all traffic through my  server(192.168.12.10) 
**Client1 -> SSH -> Server -> SSH -> Client2**

Comment: You mean you want to _route_ all traffic through your server? Client1 -> SSH -> _Server_ -> SSH -> Client2?

Comment: You would need to block traffic between clients on the switch if you want to manage centrally. Use switch ACLs, but if you have all the clients on one network segment they CAN bypass the server and talk to each other. So you need firewall on each client. Hence my answer below :)

Comment: @Lenniey,Exactly what I need.

Comment: @PHPaul,No of clients are huge , so we can't control in clients , We need to restrict switch level or server level.

Comment: @Ganapathy May I ask why you would want to do that? And: check VLANs (maybe better suited). And2: you'd still have to control your clients firewall rules

Comment: Whatever original problem you are trying to solve with this idea, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Lenniey,My goal is when any client is connect to anther client , The server has to decide whether client1 is right person to connect client2.If its wrong block the client1 request in server(12.10).

Comment: @Ganapathy if you say "person", do you mean "user"? If so, have a look at user management, not network infrastructure. Or just check Khaleds answer.

Comment: No, Person means machine( Ip based ) not user

Answer (score 3):

If the clients are also running Linux, you should also be able to block them using iptables.

For example, on client 1 if you wish to block all incoming TCP IP traffic from clients 2 and 3:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.12.2 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.12.3 -j REJECT
```

and on client 1, if you wish to block all outgoing TCP IP traffic to clients to and 3:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.12.2 -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.12.3 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Good point, have amended. Also, you can use "DROP" instead of "REJECT", but in a LAN scenario it will probably be better to say "REJECT" to avoid longer timeouts in any applications.

Comment: @PHPaul,Thanks for your response, But my requirement is , client1 trying connect to clinet2 I want to block in the server that mean 12.10, Refer my diagram

Comment: I know - should have been in the answer, rather than a comment :-)

Comment: @PHPaul,See my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

You can not simply control the traffic between your clients in the setup presented in your question. This is because clients can directly talk to each other without passing through any router or firewall. Your clients are attached to the same subnet (assuming `/24` mask).

If you want to control the traffic through some router/firewall, you need to change the subneting of your network. Each client has to be in its own subnet/VLAN. So, it needs to talk to its gateway (your server) when it needs to talk any other client.

There are other unclean options like [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing).

Answer (score 0):

There is no pass-by filtering solution in linux. So your server needs to be a transparent bridge sitting between your switch and router. Otherwise you won't be able to control clients internet access.

Solutions you can try:

1. windows pass-by filtering solution. http://www.imfirewall.us
2. linux transparent bridge. Then you can use iptables and tc for blocking and bandwidth shaping.